# Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'app' using TypeScript in AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have already deployed a Lambda Function on Node16 with JavaScript without any issues. Now I want to develop a Lambda Function on Node18 with TypeScript. I generated a Lambda Function using AWS SAM and deployed it via AWS Toolkit.

When I call the function, I get the following error message.

> 2023-08-03T14:59:27.311Z  undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception
> {
> "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
> "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'index'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
> "stack": [
> "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'index'",
> "Require stack:",
> "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
> "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:997:17)",
> "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1029:21)",
> "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1192:23)",
> "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1198:1"
> ]

How can I solve this?

**index.ts**

```
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult } from 'aws-lambda';

export const handler = async (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
    try {
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: 'hello world',
            }),
        };
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: 'some error happened',
            }),
        };
    }
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "hello_world",
  "version": "0.3.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "esbuild": "^0.14.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.92",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.4",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}
```

**template.yaml**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: An AWS Serverless Specification template describing your function.
Resources:
  generateblogpostv1:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      CodeUri: .
      Description: ''
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 900
      Role: >-
        arn:aws:iam::921222634505:role/service-role/...
      RuntimeManagementConfig:
        UpdateRuntimeOn: Auto
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es2020",
      "strict": true,
      "preserveConstEnums": true,
      "noEmit": true,
      "sourceMap": false,
      "module":"es2015",
      "moduleResolution":"node",
      "esModuleInterop": true, 
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,  
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
  }
```

Comment: Related to commonjs/es6 modules and the [type](https://dmitripavlutin.com/ecmascript-modules-nodejs/#12--type-module--in-packagejson) setting in package.json?

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem. Error is still there.

Comment: What is uploaded in your Lambda package: index.js or index.mjs?

Comment: I am using the official AWS Toolkit for IntelliJ. This tool has the ability to `Update Function Code` of an existing Lambda Function. I guess it builds the project and uploads it.

The tool builds an `index.ts`

Comment: When I run `sam build` on my own it builds just an `index.js`. But I do not know how to update an already existing Lambda Function via CLI.

Comment: Note that Lambda is not running the TypeScript code (index.ts). Node can't run TS code. It's running the JavaScript equivalent of the TS code, as produced by the tsc compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I have created my own deployment script, which works fine. The AWS Toolkit is bullshit.

```
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rm -rf dist",
    "deploy": "npm run build && aws lambda update-function-code --zip-file \"fileb://dist/index.zip\" --function-name hello-world",
    "postbuild": "cd dist && zip -r index.zip index.js*",
    "prisma:generate": "npx prisma generate"
  },
```

Comment: Where is the script of build?